# Google Analytics with Cordova app

Tags: cordova, google-analytics

I have been trying to integrate google analytics to my Cordova app without success. What i did was to include the snippet provided by google in my index.html but i see no change in the statistics. Can anyone lead me through the steps with this task? I have done one full week of intense struggle with this and failed.

Answer (score 0):

adjust the sandbox rules so your app doesn’t block requests to the Google domain. Add the following line to your config.xml to allow all outgoing request. Off course you can edit this to be more restrictive if you want.

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```